# What error code is returned by WaitForThreadTerminate when it times out?

Tags: multithreading, freepascal

The [documentation](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/waitforthreadterminate.html) for WaitForThreadTerminate states:

> If the thread does not exit within TimeoutMs milliseconds, the function will return with an error value.

Unfortunately, there is no information about what that value may be.

I guess the error code may be different for *nix and windows.  I'm only compiling with on *nix systems so that is the error code I need.

Comment: You need to read the source code

Comment: That looks dreadfully flawed.  It returns the thread exit code when it doesn't time-out.  That could match whatever error code it returns on a timeout.  No wonder they didn't document it :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading the source code, it looks like there is no consistent value.  Basically, threads are provided by a variety of different libraries depending on the platform.  Free Pascal, has a abstraction layer that provides a consistent set of functions across all threading libraries.

Unfortunately, the abstraction layer is "leaky" since it still requires the developer to know which threading library is being used.  For example, if pthreads is used, then WaitForThreadTerminate will return [pthread_join()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)'s `retval` parameter ([source reference](https://github.com/graemeg/freepascal/blob/ed184256051fbf669f49dbeb77dca30514228055/rtl/netwlibc/systhrd.inc#L202)).

Comment: The abstraction was originally only internal, to allow applications that use classes to compile without linking to libc/libpthread. (iow to make the classes - cthreads separation). If you think it deserves cleaning up, please file a bug at bugs.freepascal.org and reference this thread.

Comment: I didn't realize that it is for internal use.  I'm not heavily invested in this right now so I won't file a bug report.